# Exception thrown while trying to use smart pointers

Tags: c++, exception, design-patterns, smart-pointers

A moments ago, I was exercising with design patterns, and recently, I've tried to implement a Factory Method pattern. My friend told me that I should always use smart pointers, so I've tried it, but my compiler throws an exception called "Access Violation". What am I doing wrong? There is one interface called "Shape", three inheriting classes from it, Client class and main function. I've tried to do everything with smart pointers, but I'm a little bit unsure, if I'm doing it right.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Shape
{
public:
    virtual void printShape() = 0;
    static std::shared_ptr<Shape> Create(int num);
};

class Triangle : public Shape
{
public:
    virtual void printShape()
    {
        std::cout << "This is Triangle. \n";
    }
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    virtual void printShape()
    {
        std::cout << "This is Circle. \n";
    }
};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
    virtual void printShape()
    {
        std::cout << "This is Rectangle. \n";
    }
};

class Client
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Shape> shape;
public:
    Client()
    {
        shape=Shape::Create(1);
    }
    std::shared_ptr<Shape>getShape()
    {
        return shape;
    }
};

std::shared_ptr<Shape> Shape::Create(int num)
{
    switch (num)
    {
    case 1:
        return std::shared_ptr<Circle>();
        break;
    case 2:
        return std::shared_ptr<Triangle>();
        break;
    case 3:
        return std::shared_ptr<Rectangle>();
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Client> client;
    std::shared_ptr<Shape> shape = client->getShape();
    shape->printShape();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return statements like `return std::shared_ptr<Circle>();` just returns an empty `std::shared_ptr`, which contains nothing. Dereference on it like `shape->printShape();` leads to UB.

You should construct an object and make it managed by `std::shared_ptr`. E.g.

```
std::shared_ptr<Shape> Shape::Create(int num)
{
    switch (num)
    {
    case 1:
        return std::make_shared<Circle>();
        break;
    case 2:
        return std::make_shared<Triangle>();
        break;
    case 3:
        return std::make_shared<Rectangle>();
        break;
    }
}
```

And also for `client`.

```
std::shared_ptr<Client> client = std::make_shared<Client>();
```

Or just

```
Client client; // it seems no need to use shared_pointer for client
std::shared_ptr<Shape> shape = client.getShape();
```

Comment: Also for `std::shared_ptr<Client> client;`

Answer (score 2):

You make pointers without objects
You have to write

```
return std::shared_ptr<Circle>(new Circle());
```

Or better use std::make_shared

```
return std::make_shared<Circle>();
```